# Define any conditional in a ternary operator

Tags: angularjs

I want to change the colors of my cell, so in my table i do this on my td

```
data-ng-class="{selected.id == price.id && !price.isMinPrice ? 'selected' : '', selected.id == price.id && price.isMinPrice ? 'minSelected' : ''}"
```

i have this error:

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '.' is unexpected,
>   expecting [:] at column 10 of the expression [{selected.id == price.id
>   && !price.isMinPrice ? 'selected' : '', selected.id == price.id &&
>   price.isMinPrice ? 'minSelected' : ''}] starting at [.id == price.id
>   && !price.isMinPrice ? 'selected' : '', selected.id == price.id &&
>   price.isMinPrice ? 'minSelected' : ''}].

What is wrong ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `ng-class` expects structure like this: {'class-name' : booleanValue}, and if value is true, class will be applied.

So in your case:

`data-ng-class="{'selected' : selected.id == price.id && !price.isMinPrice, 'minSelected' : selected.id == price.id && price.isMinPrice}"`

and if you want to use ternaty operator, you can use `class` attribute with `{{}}`:

`class="{{selected.id == price.id && !price.isMinPrice ? 'selected' : ''}}"`

Answer (score 2):

You are using `ng-class` all wrong and that is why you are getting syntax errors.

You need to give it an object literal:

```
data-ng-class="{selected: selected.id == price.id && !price.isMinPrice,
                minSelected: selected.id == price.id && price.isMinPrice}"
```

This is also much cleaner than what you were trying to do.